# Is it possible to setup a private IPv6 subnet and route to the Internet?

Tags: networking, routing, ipv6

I am still trying to figure out how IPv6 works. But I had a question.

I currently have an pfSense firewall attached my Comcast service and configured with to request a v4 and  v6 WAN address from them.

As with most v4 LAN configurations I have established a private 10.0.0.0/24 subnet for my network.

As for a v6 network I have been told I have to request a routed IPv6 subnet from Comcast in order to have an internal subnet. Is this the case?

What I am wondering is if I could setup my own "private" v6 subnet and set the next hop as the address of the WAN interface. Wouldn't this work?

This right here is the part I am failing to understand... Could some please explain if this is possible?

**EDIT**

As of right now Comcast sends me a v6 address via DHCPv6-PD, I have the ability to tell pfSense to only request a prefix. Does that do anything for me?

Comment: No, you can't access the Internet with private IPv6 addresses. Use the subnets Comcast gives you.

Answer (score 1):

Comcast will send you RA packets so that your router knows what the default gateway is. You then use DHCPv6-PD to request a prefix from Comcast. That prefix is usually something like a /56 or /48. I don't know the exact amount that Comcast gives you, but it should be more than a /64. From that prefix you give /64s to your LANs. Your router will then send RA messages to the LANs so that your local devices know which IP addresses to use and what their default gateway is.

Comment: Comcast is typically giving out /60 to residential customers, which is sufficient for _most_ people (though I've already used more than half of that, I'm not most people).